# VueJS - Inactive link using Nested Routes

Tags: vue.js, django-rest-framework, vuejs2, vue-router

I'm new with Vue and with web framework in general, but I need to learn how use it and so I've decided to reabuild my personal site using VueJS 2 and Django Rest Framework. Now my web site is based on Django and hits template "generator".

I need to reproduce this kind of url: `site.name/service_name/page_slug_title`

I've created this scripts:

**ServiceList.vue**

```
import { mainApiEndpoint, apiService } from "../../common/api.service";

export default {
  name: "Services",

  data() {
    return {
      services: [],
    };
  },

  methods: {
    getServices() {
      let endpoint = mainApiEndpoint() + "services/";
      apiService(endpoint)
        .then((data) => {
          this.services.push(...data);
        });
    },
  },

  created() {
    this.getServices();
  },

};
```

**Service.vue**

```
import { mainApiEndpoint, apiService } from "../../common/api.service";

export default {
  name: "Service",

  props: {
    slug_post: {
      type: String,
      required: true,
    },
  },

  data() {
    return {
      service: {},
    };
  },

  methods: {
    getServiceDetails() {
      let endpoint = mainApiEndpoint() + `services/${this.slug_post}`;
      apiService(endpoint)
        .then((data) =>{
          this.service = data;
        });
    }
  },

  created() {
    this.getServiceDetails();
  },

};
```

And relative routes using the [Nested Routes](https://router.vuejs.org/guide/essentials/nested-routes.html):

```
  {
    path: "/servizi",
    name: "services",
    component: ServicesList,
    children: [
      {
        path: ":slug_post",
        name: "service",
        component: Service,
        props: true,
      },
    ]
  },
```

When I click on a link into the page `servizi` I can see the right url in preview but nothing happen. But if I don't use Nested Routes:

```
  {
    path: "/servizi",
    name: "services",
    component: ServicesList,
  },
  {
    path: ":slug_post",
    name: "service",
    component: Service,
    props: true,
  },
```

I can navigate to the right page but the url is incorrect, it's `site.name/page_slug_title` instead of `site.name/service_name/page_slug_title`.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem depend to the `history` mode. Passed to `hash` I've no problem.

Answer (score 0):

Your path in router/index.js is wrong. You should put full path in there

```js
  {
    path: "/servizi",
    name: "services",
    component: ServicesList,
  },
  {
    path: "/servizi/:slug_post",
    name: "service",
    component: Service,
    props: true,
  },
```

Comment: Whit your solution I see a blank page when I go to `/servizi/:slug_post`

Comment: Because your "Service" component has no template